# Returning words from a string array with symbols between them in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, bots, discord

```
public String onGoogleCommand(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 0){
        return "Type in a question after the google command!";
    }
    if(args.length >= 1){
        return "https://www.google.com/#q=" + args[0] + "+" + args[1] + "+" + args[2];
    }
    return "What?";
}
```

What I am asking about is the part where I say `return "https://www.google.com/#q=" + args[0] + "+" + args[1] + "+" + args[2];`. Obviously, this probably isn't the best way to code a search function, but how can I automate this so that the words from the String[] args automatically get put into my return statement with "+" between each of the words so that it would return something like `https://www.google.com/#q=please+help+me+with+this+question`?

Comment: just a little reminder: if you are constructing a URL, make sure you have properly escape special characters, by using things like URLEncoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `Arrays.toString` and `replace` you can achieve the result you want

```
String array[] = {"please", "help", "me"};
String output = "https://www.google.com/#q=" + Arrays.toString(array).
                    replace("[", "").
                    replace("]", "").
                    replace(", ", "+");
System.out.println(output);
```

**output**

```
 https://www.google.com/#q=please+help+me
```

Comment: Though it works, I am slightly worry about the temporary strings created by each replace.

Comment: Not a problem for this trivial example I thinks, but care should be taken when working with larger or more frequent cases

Comment: that's true :)  Another concern is, if any string contains `[`, `]` or `, `, the result will be corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

Though there is already an accepted answer, I am giving some alternatives:

1. Java 8 String join

   If you are using Java 8, it already provides a join method that you can make use of:

   ```
   return "https://www.google.com/#q=" + String.join("+", args);
   ```

   (If you are using Java < 8, there are still lots of similar util you can find, like Commons Lang)
2. Join with Loop

   It is also not difficult to write a proper and concise loop for this:

   ```
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("https://www.google.com/#q=");
   boolean first=true;
   for (String arg : args) {
       result.append(first? "" : "+").append(arg);
       first = false;
   }
   return result;
   ```

   Yet other form, as someone in comment seems does not like a boolean flag:

   ```
   StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
   for (String arg : args) {
       result.append(result.length() == 0 ? "https://www.google.com/#q=" : "+")
             .append(arg);
   }
   return result;
   ```

Comment: You don't need a `first` flag.  Instead, you can simply check once for an empty `args` list, and if not empty, then seed the query string with the first parameter.  Then, iterate over subsequent params by adding plus followed by the term.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is also a viable alternative.  It is only my personal choice as I feel it is more concise and easy to understand. I have provided another form if you are really in concern of the boolean flag.  I'd rather use a way different from yours as I like the loop to be easy to understand, instead of requiring to loop through "subsequent" elements

Comment: Well it's really a matter of efficiency; if you don't mind doing that check for each iteration, then your solution is fine.  The bigger question is what happens inside the source code for `String#join()`.  Now I'm curious how Java handles it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unless it is obviously going to affect the efficiency (e.g. string concat vs stringBuilder), I'd rather write code that is easy to understand and maintain, instead of focusing on such kind of premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method :

```
public static String join(String[] array, String separator) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if (separator == null) {
            separator = "";
        }

        if (array.length <= 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(array.length * 16);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    buf.append(separator);
                }

                if (array[i] != null) {
                    buf.append(array[i]);
                }
            }

            return buf.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

It's actually imported from `org.apache.commons.lang3;` package

Example :

```
public static String onGoogleCommand(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        return "Type in a question after the google command!";
    }
    if (args.length >= 1) {
        return "https://www.google.com/#q=" + join(args, "+");
    }
    return "What?";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the `args[]` array and build your query string:

```
public String onGoogleCommand(String[] args) {
    if(args == null || args.length == 0) {
        return "Type in a question after the google command!";
    }
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("https://www.google.com/#q=");
    queryString.append(args[0]);
    for (int i=1; i < args.length; ++i) {
        queryString.append("+").append(args[i]);
    }

    return queryString.toString();
}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("https://www.google.com/#q="); queryString .append (args[0]` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Helps to have a cup of coffee before logging in :~P

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use a foreach loop, something like this can help:

```
if(args.length >= 1){
    String finalStr="";
    for(String currentStr:args){
        finalStr+=currentStr+"+";
    }
    finalStr= finalStr.substring(0, finalStr.length()-1);
}
```

Using this code you will have your search in finalStr, just append it's value to your URL, as you can see the symbol "+" is added after each element and I always remove the last element ("+") because it's unnecessary at the end of the String.